# Prevent from dynamically changings with ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have some fields to edit user' data. One of the field is also used in breadcrumb:
[image: Same data]

I use `ng-model` to bind all the fields:

```
...
<ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">{{user.name}}</a></li>
        <li class="active">Profile</li>
        <li class="active">Edit</li>
    </ol>
    <hr>
    <form role="form" class="col-sm-2">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" placeholder="Username" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" ng-value="user.birthday" placeholder="Birthday" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
            </span>
            <input type="text" ng-value="user.city" placeholder="City" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button id="submit" ng-click="saveUser(user)" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Save</button>
    </form>
...
```

The problem and also the right behavior of `ng-model` changes  the name value of breadcrumb on input updating:
[image]
Is it possible to set value in breadcrumb as a static and prevent it from changing?
The actual result I want to achieve:
[image: result to achieve]

Comment: Explain how you would prefer the whole process to work. Will breadcumb get updated after user saves changes? Can you not use a copy of object for the breadcrumb?

Comment: @charlietfl I've updated my question. Take a look

Comment: could always set a different property for breadcrumb. Lots of ways around this

Comment: You dont want to apply two way binding or delay that until focus goes out from the input field?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is that I should use one-time data-binding using `::` on my `li` element in the breadcrumb like so:

```
<li><a href="#">{{::user.name}}</a></li>
```

It prevents data from future changing once it was rendered.